# how to make flexbox working with a vertical scrollbar and child div having min-height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following markup, when there is no vertical space enough for the `page` div and a vertical scrollbar is in place, the `app-sidebar` div is not stretched to fill the vertical space and is limited by the height of the viewport.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.viewport {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.app {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app-header {
  height: 48px;
  background: #AAAAAA;
}

.app-body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.app-sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  background: #999999;
}

.app-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.feature {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.feature-header {
  height: 48px;
  background: #888888;
}

.feature-body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.page {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  background: #777777;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app-header">
    </div>
    <div class="app-body">
      <div class="app-sidebar">
      </div>
      <div class="app-content">
        <div class="feature">
          <div class="feature-header">
          </div>
          <div class="feature-body">
            <div class="page">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8eKD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `min-height` on `.viewport`, here simplified using viewport units instead.

*Note, IE11 doesn't like `flex: 1` (which make `flex-basis` be 0/0px), so either use `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1 1 auto` (which I didn't changed in below sample).*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.viewport {
  min-height: 100vh;               /*  changed  */
  display: flex;
}

.app {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app-header {
  height: 48px;
  background: #AAAAAA;
}

.app-body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.app-sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  background: #999999;
}

.app-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.feature {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.feature-header {
  height: 48px;
  background: #888888;
}

.feature-body {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.page {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  min-height: 400px;
  max-height: 800px;
  background: #777777;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app-header">
    </div>
    <div class="app-body">
      <div class="app-sidebar">
      </div>
      <div class="app-content">
        <div class="feature">
          <div class="feature-header">
          </div>
          <div class="feature-body">
            <div class="page">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution in a standalone html page and it didn't work. Not sure why it works in this preview.

Comment: @user2914785 Show me that html page ... and which browser did you use?

Comment: I just copy/pasted the html tag from the preview into a separate file and then opened it in chrome and safari.

Comment: @user2914785 Well, you can't use only that html, it miss doctype, html tag, body tag, etc. Here is a complete: http://jsfiddle.net/8v8pq4nq/

Comment: omg... so it was because of <!DOCTYPE html>. even my original html is working fine with it. anyway, thanks for help